# Create a modal window/dialog window in Outlook Web Add-In

Tags: javascript, html, xml, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to make a modal window in Outlook Web Add-In but I can't find nothing about that. The TaskPane is not comfortable to use when I have a lot of data to display.

I tried to add this to my code:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://www.contoso.com/myDialog.html', {height: 30, width: 20});
```

from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins

and got nothing.

Any idea or suggestion are accepted. Thanks :)

Comment: Read the link.  You are missing the TRUE option.,  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#take-advantage-of-a-performance-option-in-office-on-the-web

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code still not working properly, the dialog window doesn't pop up and the only thing that appear is the task pane.

Comment: Put a break point on the Async method and see if code gets there.  We need to know if the Async Method is working, or the issue is a View issue.

Comment: Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-handle-errors-events#errors-from-displaydialogasync for the various error scenarios and check if any of them is being returned by Add-in API.